# MVC - Sending Value of a field with request/session via a JSP

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a list of members of type Party, and linking their memberID to an update page which automatically gets the memberID of the one which was clicked.

I've already written code in the servlet to display a view of all of the members, with each of their IDs linked to a page called UpdateParty.jsp however what I want is for the ID clicked to be passed on with the request so that it can be used in the UpdateParty.jsp as a parameter so that the user does not have to enter it.

I'm using **postgres** for my SQL if anyone wants to know.

**Servlet code which produces a list of all party members:**

```
  else if (request.getParameter("listallmembers") != null) {
                    try {

                        User sessionuser = (User) session.getAttribute("User");
                        String u = sessionuser.getUsername();
                        ArrayList<Party> p = new ArrayList<Party>();
                        ResultSet rs = this.findAllMembers(u);

                        while (rs.next()) {
                            Party party = new Party();

                            party.setMemberID(rs.getString("memberID"));
                            party.setPartyFirstname(rs.getString("partyFirstname"));
                            party.setPartySurname(rs.getString("partySurname"));
                            party.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));

                            p.add(party);
                        }

                        request.setAttribute("members", p);
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("ViewPartyMembers.jsp").forward(request, response);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        out.print(e);
                        e.printStackTrace(out);
                    }
```

**Code for ViewPartyMembers.jsp:**

```
<%@page import="HolidayExchange.Party"%>
<%@page import="HolidayExchange.User"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>All Party Members</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>View Party Members</h1>



        <%
        List<Party> l = (List<Party>) request.getAttribute("members");

        if(l!=null){
            out.println("<table>");
            out.println("<tr><th>Member ID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Second Name</th><th>Associated User</th></tr>");
            for(int i = 0; i < l.size();i++){
                    out.println("<tr><td>"+ l.get(i).getMemberID() +
                            "</td><td><a href='UpdateParty.jsp'>"+ l.get(i).getPartyFirstname() + 
                            "</a></td><td>"+ l.get(i).getPartySurname() + 
                            "</td><td>" + l.get(i).getUsername() + "</td>");
                    out.println("</tr>");
            }
            out.println("</table>");
        }else{
        %>

        <form action="PartyServlet" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="listallmembers" value="1" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Show all Members" />
        </form>

        <%

        }
        %>



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something a little more sane for you. It uses the JSTL Expression Language and tag library.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>All Party Members</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>View Party Members</h1>

    <c:if test="${!empty members}">
        <table>
            <tr><th>Member ID</th><th>Firstname</th><th>Second Name</th><th>Associated User</th></tr>
            <c:forEach items="${members}" var="member">
                <tr><td>${member.memberID}</td>
                <c:url value="link" value="UpdateParty.jsp">
                    <c:param name="memberId" value="${member.memberID}"/>
                </c:url>
                <td><a href="${link}">${member.partyFirstname}</a></td>
                <td>${member.partySurname}</td>
                <td>${member.username}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${empty members}">
        <form action="PartyServlet" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="listallmembers" value="1" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Show all Members" />
        </form>
    </c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ID to be available on the UpdateParty.jsp your link should look like:

```
<a href='UpdateParty.jsp?id=" + l.get(i).getMemberID() + "'>"+ l.get(i).getPartyFirstname()"</a>
```

So the id property will be available in the JSP as a request parameter.

Anyway, I recommend you not use scriptlet in your JSP and instead point directly to a JSP point to a Controler/Action

Comment: Ideally I want to do it all via the controller, however I wasn't sure how to pass the value of linked piece of text onto the update servlet without directly working on the hyperlinked field.

Comment: Use a link to pass id to the JSP/Contoller is not a bad approach.